# Assert that the list is not empty - with or without Hamcrest?

Tags: java, collections, junit, hamcrest

This is related to [Checking that a List is not empty in Hamcrest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631110/checking-that-a-list-is-not-empty-in-hamcrest)

I have a question over that - If we can assert the list is not empty without using Hamcrest and just using JUnit as:

```
assertFalse(list.isEmpty());
```

Is using

```
assertThat(list.isEmpty(), is(false));
```

or

```
assertThat((Collection)list, is(not(empty())));
```

Worthwhile?

I'm not able to understand are we gaining something using Hamcrest version in this case? Are both equivalent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the same functionality. The hamcrest provides a more English-like readable language and better error messages. In simple cases like this, I would probably just use the `assertFalse`