# assert that a list is not empty in JUnit

Tags: junit, junit4

I want to assert that a list is not empty in JUnit 4, when I googled about it I found this post : [Checking that a List is not empty in Hamcrest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3631110/4991526) which was using Hamcrest.

```
assertThat(result.isEmpty(), is(false));
```

which gives me this error :

> The method is(boolean) is undefined for the type
>   MaintenanceDaoImplTest

how can I do that without using `Hamcrest`.

Comment: See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631110/checking-that-a-list-is-not-empty-in-hamcrest

Comment: Just for reference: `assertThat(items, IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(greaterThan(1)))` checks the size of the collection.
But unfortunately it doesn't print items in the collection in case of failure :(

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can simply use

```
assertFalse(result.isEmpty());
```

Regarding your problem, it's simply caused by the fact that you forgot to statically import the `is()` method from Hamcrest;

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
```

Comment: now the better approach is the `assertThat(myList, is(not(empty())));`

Comment: @GiulioCaccin Mentioning the import classes would be helpful.

Comment: I did not mention it because the proper answer from LazerBanana is right here on page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279675/1636173

Comment: How would you extend this to check if a file is empty?

Answer (score 43):

This reads quite nicely and uses Hamcrest. Exactly what you asked for ;)
Always nice when the code reads like a comment.

```
assertThat(myList, is(empty()));
assertThat(myList, is(not(empty())));
```

**You can add `is` as a static import to your IDE as I know that eclipse and IntelliJ is struggling with suggesting it even when it is on the classpath.**

---

### IntelliJ

```
Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports
```

### Eclipse

```
Prefs -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favourites
```

And the import itself is
    `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;`

Comment: what about `empty()` it's not resolved for me, is it user-defined too or need static import?

Comment: @basheer : import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.empty;

Answer (score 5):

You can check if your list is not equal an Empty List (`Collections.EMPTY_LIST`), try this:

```
Assertions.assertNotEquals(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, yourList);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use

```java
Assert.assertEquals(List.of(), result)
```

That way, you get a really good error message if the list isn't empty. E.g.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[]
Actual   :[something unexpected]
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
assertEquals(Collections.Empty_List,Collections.emptyList())
```

Try this.

Answer (score -2):

I was also looking for something similar, but the easiest work around can be

```
Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 0);
```

When the collection has no records.

Answer (score -2):

You can change "is" to "equalTo":
assertThat(result.isEmpty(), equalTo(false));

Comment: What imports are you using for this? Is it without using Hamcrest?